# Downloading the file from email is not happening directly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am doing automation in IE, when I found attachment in my mail, I click the download button to download files, In chrome it directly downloads into the download folder, but in IE, when I press the download button, it opens the yellow color bar in the bottom, it gives me the option 'save','open','cancel', My question here is, Is there anyway I could able to cancel out this bar so that download directly happens inside download folder like the way it happens in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any specific information about your application, but this MSDN link [Customizing the download experience](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj542450(v=vs.85).aspx) explains several possible options.